# Escape single backslash inbetween non-backslash characters only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, string, escaping

I have some input coming in a web page which I will re display and submit elsewhere. The current issue is that I want to double up all **single** backslashes that are sandwiched inbetween non-backslash characters before submitting the input elsewhere.

Test string `"domain\name\\nonSingle\\\WontBe\\\\Returned"`, I want to only get the first single backslash, between domain and name.

This string should get nothing `"\\get\\\nothing\\\\"`

My **current pattern** that I can get closest with is `[\w][\\](?!\\)` however this will get the `"\n"` from the 1st test string i have listed. I would like to use lookbehind for the regex however javascript does not have such a thing for the version I am using. Here is the site I have been testing my regexs on http://www.regexpal.com/

Currently I am inefficiently using this regex `[\w][\\](?!\\)` to extract out all single backslashes sandwiched between non-backslash characters **and the character before them (which I don't want)** and then replacing it with the same string plus a backslash at the end of it.

For example given `domain\name\\bl\\\ah` my current regex `[\w][\\]\(?!\\)` will return `"n\"`. This results in my code having to do some additional processing rather than just using replace.

I don't care about any double, triple or quadruple backslashes present, they can be left alone.

Comment: What is the regex operation on `domain\name\previousBackslashesUnwanted` supposed to return? This is unclear to me

Comment: Test string "domain\name\\previousBackslashesUnwanted" , I want to get only the single \ between domain and name. 

The desired regex should return nothing given the test string \\\\get\\\\nothing. 

The closest regex I have is [\w][\\\](?!\\\) (I'm having trouble with escaping here but there should only be 2 backslashes in the middle square bracket and the round brackets) returns the 1st character before a singular backslash. regexpal.com

Comment: What do you want to do with the match? Replace it with something else? Split the string? Or highlight it for the user?

Comment: I want to replace single back slashes sandwiched between non backlashes with a double backslash

Answer (score 1):

> For example given `domain\name\\bl\\\ah` my current regex `[\w][\\]\(?!\\)` will return `"n\"`. This results in my code having to do some additional processing rather than just using replace.

It will do *just using replace*, since you can insert the matched substring with `$&`, see:

```js
console.log(String.raw`domain\name\\bl\\\ah`.replace(/\w\\(?!\\)/g, "$&\\"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest method of matching escapes, is to match all escaped characters.

```
\\(.)
```

And then in the replacement, decide what to do with it based on what was captured.

```js
var s = "domain\\name\\\\backslashesInDoubleBackslashesWontBeReturned";
console.log('input:', s);

var r = s.replace(/\\(.)/g, function (match, capture1) {
    return capture1 === '\\' ? match : '$' + capture1;
});
console.log('result:', r);
```

The closest you can get to actually matching the unescaped backslashes is

```
((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\\\)*)\\(?!\\)
```

It will match an odd number of backslashes, and capture all but the last one into capture group 1.

```js
var re = /((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\\\)*)\\(?!\\)/g;
var s = "domain\\name\\\\escapedBackslashes\\\\\\test";

var parts = s.split(re);
console.dir(parts);

var cleaned = [];
for (var i = 1; i < parts.length; i += 2)
{
    cleaned.push(parts[i-1] + parts[i]);
}
cleaned.push(parts[parts.length - 1]);
console.dir(cleaned);
```

The even-numbered (counting from zero) items will be unmatched text. The odd-numbered items will be the captured text.

Each captured text should be considered part of the preceding text.

Comment: My apologies for being unclear, I have updated the sample test strings in my question. My current solution doesn't trigger on triple backslashes. I do not need to process any odd number consecutive of backslashes > 1.  I only desire a regex triggering on single backslash surrounded by non-backslash characters. I can process less matches by using my current regex.